# Why do I get an imaginary result for the cube root of a negative number?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, radicals, roots-of-unity

I have a function that includes the phrase $(-x)^{1/3}$. It seems like this should always evaluate to $-(x^{1/3})$. For example, $-1 \cdot -1 \cdot -1 = -1$, so it seems that $(-1)^{1/3}$ should equal $-1$.

When I plug $(-1)^{(1/3)}$ into something like Mathematica, I get:

```
0.5 + 0.866025i
```

Cubing this answer does in fact compute to $-1$.

Is this a situation, like $\sqrt4$, where there are two valid answers , $\{-2, 2\}$?

Comment: For the $\sqrt{4}$, the only "answer" is $2$. However, for $x^2=4$, the equation is satisfied by $\pm 2$.

Comment: $\sqrt{4}$ has only one answer, namely $2$.  $4^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on the other hand has two answers.  $\sqrt{4}$ and $4^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are two completely different notations meaning two different things.

Comment: Every number has two square roots ($\sqrt a$ and $-\sqrt a$). Every number also has three (possibly complex) cube roots, four (possibly complex) fourth roots, etc.

Comment: The three cube roots of $1$ are: $1$, $-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$, and $-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2$. It turns out that, when you draw them on the complex plane, they are the corners of an equilateral triangle. (The cube roots of $-1$ are the negatives of these.)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root

Comment: Since you refer to Mathermatica, use the function [Surd](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html). "Surd[x, n] 
gives the real-valued n^th root of x."

Answer (score 5):

The end result is that $x^y$ is technically a *multi-valued* function whenever $y$ is not an integer.  This is often overlooked in favor of considering only the *principal root* (smallest argument greater than or equal to zero) as is the case with the square root (which will result in real numbers only in the case that $x$ is a non-negative real number).  In the further case that $y$ is an irrational number, then there are infinitely many solutions.

Here, I will attempt to go into more detail about the case where $y$ is a simple fraction with $1$ as the numerator.

> **De Moivre's Theorem for fractional powers:** for a complex number in polar form with $r$ a non-negative real number, one has
> $$(r(cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{r}\left[\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi+\theta}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi+\theta}{n}\right)\right]~~\text{for}~k=0,1,2,\dots,n-1$$

Graphically, if one were to want to find the results of $z^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for some complex number $z$, plot it on the complex plane.  Take the magnitude of $z$
and replace it with the magnitude of $\sqrt[n]{|z|}$.  Take the angle of $z$ and replace it with $\frac{1}{n}$ of that angle.  From there, draw a regular $n$-gon with one of the points being the just found point.  All of the corners will be the solutions.

[image: roots]

Pictured above is the original number $z$ (in red), and its three cube roots (in blue).

Comment: *Principal* root.

Comment: @Did I can never keep the spelling straight in my head.

Comment: One of the roots in your illustration is plotted incorrectly. It will be on the positive-x side of the negative y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Use $e^{i\pi}=-1$. Then $(e^{i\pi})^{1/3}=e^{i\pi/3}=-1^{1/3}$

De Moivre's gives $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$

If $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$, then it follows that

$(-1)^{1/3}=e^{i(\pi/3)}=\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}{2}\approx0.5 + 0.866025i$

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes, I only want the real solution among the three possible valid solutions. Is there a way to force that?

Comment: there are k-roots of $-1^{1/k}$ - most Math software returns the $1^{st}$. View this as $-1^{j/k}$ to get the $j^{th}$ root and $-1$ is the $k^{th}$ root